# Changing DRF API ViewSet page title(s)?

Tags: django-rest-framework

I'm trying to change the title of an API ViewSet list page (really the titles/references of all the views it generates) as the model name is not what I'd like the user to see

I have tried changing both the 'name' and 'basename' attributes of the ViewSet but neither of these has affected the title so any advice on the correct means to do so would be great. In researching the issue it seems like changing these attributes should do so but they have (obviously) not.

Answer (score 1):

Try defining a `get_view_name()` method of the `Viewset Class`.

Example:

```
class BookViewset(viewsets.ViewSet):
    def get_view_name(self):
        return "Book Viewset"
```